# How to save the filepath of a picture to a database to be dynamic based on the computer in Visual Studio Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am saving pictures to a database by saving the filepath, then copying the file to the root folder of the database. However, although the code to get the picture of the computer and save it is dynamic, actually saving the filepath of the picture to the database is not.

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog(); //open file explorer 
open.Filter = "All Images Files (*.png;*.jpeg;*jpg) | *.png;*.jpeg;*jpg"; 

if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   
{
    string path = @open.FileName;   
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @open.FileName;
}

string parent = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
string source = @pictureBox1.ImageLocation; 
string filename = Path.GetFileName(source); 
parent = @parent + @"images\"; 

string destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(parent, filename); 
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @destfile;   

File.Copy(source, destfile);
```

The former code was to save and copy the file to the project folder then to get the new file path of that file in the project folder. The path is then saved to the database in a `nvarchar` column.

But as you can see, the file path only works for 1 PC. Is there a way to make it so that saving it in the database only requires the location of the root folder?

Comment: You say you're saving to 'the root folder of the database' (which I don't really understand), but then go on to say you've 'saved to the database in an `nvarchar` column'. Neither of those claims seems to relate to the code. I'm struggling to work out what you're asking or why it 'only works for 1 PC'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either, but this code should technically work if you throw in a line to create the images folder: `Directory.CreateDirectory("images");`. As far as the database value, it would just always be a relative path like ".\images\some_image.png". I say "technically" because you don't handle the user cancelling the dialog and you don't clean up Disposables.